# Scala polymorphic callback type mismatch

Tags: scala, types, callback, polymorphism, case-class

I'm sorry i couldn't find a better title.

I'm trying to achieve something like the following

```
abstract class Person 

case class User(uid: String, firstname: String, active: String) extends Person
case class Admin(id: String, pseudo: String, securityClearance: String) extends Person

def innerFunctionForUser(user: User): List[String] = {
  List() :+ user.uid :+ user.firstname :+ user.active
}

def innerFunctionForAdmin(admin: Admin): List[String] = {
  List() :+ admin.id :+ admin.psuedo :+ admin.securityClearance
}

def outerFunction(person: Person, innerFunction: (Person) => List[String]): List[String] = {
  innerFunction(person)
}
```

so i could use it like that

```
val myUser = User("0c60c5b4-306d-4372-b60d-fd699c80e408", "joe", "false")
val myAdmin = Admin("178789", "jack", "high")

outerFunction(myUser, innerFunctionForUser)
outerFunction(myAdmin, innerFunctionForAdmin)
```

which does not type check

```
type mismatch;
 found   : User => List[String]
 required: Person => List[String]
```

and i can't have the innerFunction accept a type person like this

```
def innerFunctionForUser(user: Person): List[String] = {
  List() :+ user.uid :+ user.firstname :+ user.active
}
```

I kept it simple here but i need case class with parameters of different type and different  number of parameters.
So i can't have them declared in the abstract class Person.
Which would give

```
value uid is not a member of Person

value firstname is not a member of Person

value active is not a member of Playground.Person
```

How can one make different case class with different parameters in types and numbers evaluate to the same type ?

AND/OR

How can one make a a callback polymorphic, kind a like this

```
def outerFunction(person: Person, innerFunction: (SomeCaseClass) => List[String]): List[String] = {
  innerFunction(person)
}
```

Hope this is clear enough.

Thanks for reading, Have a good One.

Comment: BTW, `List() :+ user.uid :+ user.firstname :+ user.active` is not common and readable. You can just: `List(user.uid, user.firstname, user.active)` or `user.uid :: user.firstname :: user.active :: Nil` _(I would go with the former)_. BTW, it seems you may want to give it a look to [**typeclasses**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

Comment: I realize that the posted code is probably a gross simplification of your actual requirements, but if all you really need is a `List[String]` of `case class` parameters then `def innerFunc(p:Product):List[String] = p.productIterator.map(_.toString).toList` will do it for you.

Comment: Yes this was just for example sake but it is kind of stupid, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`User` and `Admin` are subtypes of `Person` but `User => List[String]` and `Admin => List[String]` are not *subtypes* of `Person => List[String]`. `User => List[String]` and `Admin => List[String]` are actually *supertypes* of `Person => List[String]`. Function type `A => B` is [covariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html) with respect to `B` but contravariant with respect to `A`.

Try to make `outerFunction` [generic](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html)

```
def outerFunction[P <: Person](person: P, innerFunction: P => List[String]): List[String] = 
  innerFunction(person)

outerFunction(myUser, innerFunctionForUser) //List(0c60c5b4-306d-4372-b60d-fd699c80e408, joe, false)
outerFunction(myAdmin, innerFunctionForAdmin) //List(178789, jack, high)
```

You can also try to replace functions `innerFunctionForUser`, `innerFunctionForAdmin` with [type class](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/type-classes-101-introduction/)

```
trait InnerFunction[P <: Person] {
  def apply(person: P): List[String]
}

object InnerFunction {
  implicit val forUser: InnerFunction[User] = 
    user => List(user.uid, user.firstname, user.active)
  implicit val forAdmin: InnerFunction[Admin] = 
    admin => List(admin.id, admin.pseudo, admin.securityClearance)
}

def outerFunction[P <: Person](person: P)(implicit innerFunction: InnerFunction[P]): List[String] = 
  innerFunction(person)

outerFunction(myUser) //List(0c60c5b4-306d-4372-b60d-fd699c80e408, joe, false)
outerFunction(myAdmin) //List(178789, jack, high)
```

Since type class `InnerFunction` acts on different data types now similarly (it produces list of values for all fields of a case class) you can even *derive* it:

```
trait InnerFunction[T] {
  def apply(t: T): List[String]
}

object InnerFunction {
  implicit def mkInnerFunction[T <: Product]: InnerFunction[T] =
    _.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).toList
}

def outerFunction[T](t: T)(implicit innerFunction: InnerFunction[T]): List[String] = 
  innerFunction(t)

      //or simply
// def outerFunction[T <: Product](t: T): List[String] =
//   t.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).toList
      //or
// def outerFunction(t: Product): List[String] =
//   t.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).toList

outerFunction(myUser) //List(0c60c5b4-306d-4372-b60d-fd699c80e408, joe, false)
outerFunction(myAdmin) //List(178789, jack, high)
```

(this will fail at runtime if not all fields of `T` are `String`s) [or](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToList
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}

trait InnerFunction[T] {
  def apply(t: T): List[String]
}

object InnerFunction {
  implicit def mkInnerFunction[T <: Product, L <: HList](implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[T, L],
    toList: ToList[L, String]
  ): InnerFunction[T] = generic.to(_).toList
}

def outerFunction[T](t: T)(implicit innerFunction: InnerFunction[T]): List[String] = 
  innerFunction(t)

      //or simply
// def outerFunction[T, L <: HList](t: T)(implicit
//   generic: Generic.Aux[T, L],
//   toList: ToList[L, String]
// ): List[String] = generic.to(t).toList

outerFunction(myUser) //List(0c60c5b4-306d-4372-b60d-fd699c80e408, joe, false)
outerFunction(myAdmin) //List(178789, jack, high)
```

(this will guarantee at compile time that all fields of `T` are `String`s).