# case class inheritance from trait behaving unexpectedly

Tags: scala, variance

I have a trait of `Person`, and a case class which inherit from this trait, I would expect if I have a function that except a function from `Person` to `Future[Person]` and I would pass it func from `Male` to `Future[Male]` that would pass. like this:

```
trait Person {
  val name: String
  val age: Int
}

case class Male (override val name: String, override val age: Int, height: Double) extends Person

val male1 = Male(name = "John", age = 30, height = 1.80)

def something(person: Person => Future[Person]): Unit = {
  println(s"person is $person")
}

def maleToFutureMale (male: Male) = Future.successful(male)

something(maleToFutureMale)
```

but get compilation error:

[image]

Comment: It's contravariance. A `Male` is a `Person` but a `Male => Future[Male]` is not a `Person => Future[Person]` because it must be passed at value that is a `Male`. Imagine calling `maleToFutureMale(aFemale)`. If you could pass it to `something`, `something` could do that

Comment: so how can I do something like this? cause i do want this behavior,  to create a function that will take and class that inherits from Person and run ```something``` on it. i want to pass for instance, male func from matl to future male and female to future female to ```something``` @AluanHaddad

Comment: Without more context, I would write `def something[P <: Person](toFuture: P => Future[P]): Unit`. It depends on what you do with the function however. In your example it isn't invoked.

Comment: To add to this, Function1 is contravariant in it's parameter type and covariant in it's result type. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Function1.html

That means you can have a function there where the input is a super type of Person and the result a subtype.

Other languages like Kotlin make this more approachable to newcomers with the in/out annotation, where in scala we have + and -.

@AluanHaddad would you write your comment as an answer so we can upvote/accept it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660986/scala-polymorphic-callback-type-mismatch/

Comment: BTW use `defs` in traits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to case classes or traits, it has to do with the function subtyping.

Scala rejects such code because, while a `Male` is a `Person`, a `Male => Future[Male]` is not a `Person => Future[Person]`.

To understand why, consider the following type

```
case class Female(val name, val age) extends Person
```

and the following delta on your `something` method

```
def something(personToFuture: Person => Future[Person]): Unit = {
  val future = personToFuture(Female("Lisa", 53))
}
```

The above code is perfectly correct. We can pass a `Female` to `personToFuture` because a `Female` is a `Person`.

If the language allowed us to pass `maleToFutureMale` to `something`, then it would be allowing us to pass a `Female` to a function expecting a `Male`.

All this is not to say that function types are invariant, that the argument you pass to `something` must have the type `Person => Future[Person]`. Function types do indeed have subtyping relationships.

Function types are [*contravariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) in their parameter types and [*covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) in their return types.

In general, given a function type, `F`, a function type with *less* specific parameter types and a *more* specific return type is a subtype of `F`.

For example, the following is perfectly valid

```
val anyToFutureOfMale: Any => Future[Male] = _ => Future.successful(Male("Robert", 39, 1.8))

something(anyToFutureOfMale)
```

The above is valid because an `Any => Male` is a `Person => Person`. As a `Person` is an `Any` it is perfectly sound to pass a `Person` to a function expecting an `Any` and, likewise, as a `Male` is a `Person` it perfectly sound to receive a `Male` from a function returning a `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're mixing subtyping with co/contravariance.
Male is a Person, a Male => Future[Male] is not a Person => Future[Person].